# Selenium-java,TestNG and jenkins on CentOS

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, testng, centos7

I have recently setup integration of **Selenium** (Java bindings) with **TestNG** and **Jenkins** in a Windows environment, which is running absolutely fine.

I have created a batch file of **TestNG** and executed it through Jenkins using Windows batch file command. Now the situation is that I have to run these Selenium test cases on a **Linux** (Centos 7) environment as the Jenkins is setup there.

I am not quite sure how I should approach that. I have gone through some articles, but really could not find anything related to this for Selenium/Java things.

I have already done some initial steps, but I'm stuck after that:

1. I have setup **CentOS 7**;
2. Installed **Java** on it;
3. Installed **Jenkins** on it;
4. I have also installed **xvfb** as it would be required for headless execution.

From here I need some guidance in terms of how to proceed further, or put all things together. For example, should I move Selenium/Java project on VM and somehow run the **TestNG** file through **Jenkins**? (but not sure how to do that need some steps to follow or are there any more prerequisite to it). Or some other approach which is better.

It would be great if someone can guide me towards any article or can explain here with steps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you can try doing to get this working:

1. You need a version control system(VCS) such as GIT/SVN, wherein you would need to push in your test code. That way, your Jenkins Instance will be able to pull in code from the VCS.
2. Once you have pushed in your code into the VCS, you can create a build job which would pull code from your VCS, build it using a build tool such as Maven/Gradle/Ant and then execute your tests (again using the build tool)

To learn how to setup your Jenkins instance with Git (One of the popular VCS flavors), please refer to [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Jenkins/article.html) blog.

To learn how to go about setting up a Continuous Integration system with Selenium, you can also refer to [this](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/continuous-integration-with-selenium/) blog post of mine.

Comment: Thanks Krishnan Mahadevan for guiding and pointing into some direction i am currently using bit bucket. I don't know why my question was marked negatively. although i tried explaining what i have done so far and what i am looking to do and just need some guidance as i was unable to find something on the internet. I really appreciate your help in this regard.